# Yii : clear data form table after delete post

Tags: php, yii

I used `yii blog from Yii Framework`

I want clear data from like table after delete post

I used This code at Post Model

```
protected function afterDelete()
{
    parent::afterDelete();
    Like::model()->deleteAll('post_id='.$this->id);

}
```

But Not Delete data from Like Table after delete post

Comment: Can't you write the delete code in the controller, where you're deleting the post ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you put your code in a beforeDelete, not afterDelete, I think it is better to first delete related data and then the main object.

I also suggest opening CActiveRecord class from YiiFramework and look how exactly are the methods defined, see if you are using the right (public/protected) and if you need to return a "true" or no need to return anything.

Here's a working example of beforeDelete:

```
protected function beforeDelete() {
  if (parent::beforeDelete()) {

    // requests
    Yii::app()->db->createCommand("DELETE FROM x2_oirequest_city WHERE city_id={$this->id}")->execute();

    return true;
  }
}
```